# Spring: ModelAttribute values get lost after returning ModelAndView in <form:input>

Tags: java, spring, model, modelattribute, modelandview

I am facing the problem, that some ModelAttribute values get lost after returning ModelAndView.

**Example:**

Here are all statistic items properly filled. I can see each correct value in debug mode. Everything seem to be fine:

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.addObject("materialStatistic", statisticsService.fillStatistic(statisticHelper));
return mav;
```

But on the JSP the data seem to have been lost: (only NULL values)

```
<c:forEach items="${materialStatistic.materialOccurences}" var="occurence" varStatus="occurenceStatus"> 
    <td>
        <form:input path="materialOccurences[${occurenceStatus.index}].averageM2" cssClass="inputFieldShort"/>
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Also very strange is, if I print out the fields like following, I receive the data: (correct Float values)

```
${occurence.averageM2}
```

Why can `<form:input>` not resolve my fields?

---

**Update 1:**

Form declaration:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="materialStatistic" action="" id="statistic-material-form" method="POST">
```

Generated code of `<form:input>`

```
<input id="materialOccurences20.averageM2" class="inputFieldShort" type="text" value="" name="materialOccurences[20].averageM2">
```

**Update 2:**

StrictFloatPropertyEditor:

`this.getValue()` is always null

```
public class StrictFloatPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ProposalService.class);
    private Locale locale;
    private boolean allowDigits;
    private boolean round;

    public StrictFloatPropertyEditor(boolean allowDigits, boolean round, Locale locale) {
        this.allowDigits = allowDigits;
        this.locale = locale;
        this.round = round;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Float parsedText = new Float(0);
        try {
            DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
            if (formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator() == ',') {
                text = text.replaceAll("\\.", ",");
            }
            parsedText = formatter.parse(text).floatValue();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
                logger.error("Parse Exception occured. Value set to zero: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        super.setValue(parsedText);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        if(allowDigits){
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
            nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            String numberAsText = nf.format(this.getValue());
            return numberAsText;
        }else if(round){
            float number = (Float) this.getValue();
            Integer roundedNumber = Math.round(number);
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
            String numberAsText = nf.format(roundedNumber);
            return numberAsText;
        }else{
            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
            String numberAsText = nf.format(this.getValue());
            return numberAsText;
        }
    }
}
```

InitBinder:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Float.TYPE, "materialOccurences.averageM2", new StrictFloatPropertyEditor(true, true, request.getLocale()));
    }
```

Comment: What do you see in the HTML? Are you getting the `<input>` tags you expect? what is the value of the path attribute?

Comment: Have you declared a `<form:form>` outside the `<form:input>` to bind the model attribute? Also, what exactly is `null` in your example?

Comment: Created input tags are correctly. Cause if I set the values on JSP and pass them back to controller, all values arrive properly.Yes <form:form> inclusive a model attribute is available. (see update)

Comment: Yes it does. As described the ModelAttribte "materialStatistic" contains only correct data while returning ModelAndView. Moreover the data is available if I print it out via ${value}. For me its very strange.

Comment: What is the type of your `materialOccurences` field?

Comment: List<MaterialOccurrence>  --> Helper class, only containing several private fields with pulbic getter/setter.

Comment: Did you use the @ModelAttribute annotation in your controller method?

Comment: Yes I did: `public ModelAndView loadMaterialStatistic(@ModelAttribute(value="materialStatistic") MaterialStatistic statistic,BindingResult result) {}`

Comment: You hadn't said anything about the custom `PropertyEditor`. Can you post it?

Comment: Please check update 2, but I dont think that this is the problem, cause I use the custom editor at several other points and there it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't tactically need to use the spring tag.

JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${materialStatistic.materialOccurences}" var="occurence" varStatus="occurenceStatus"> 
    <td>
        <input class="inputFieldShort" type="text" value="${occurence.averageM2}" name="materialOccurences[${occurenceStatus.index}].averageM2">
    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: The problem is that I use an custom PropertyEditor for Floats (for correct decimals). And within the overriden `setAsText()`/`getAsText()` Methods I also receive null values..

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**

As things stand, the data get lost somewhere between Controller and StrictFloatPropertyEditor. I guess no JSP problem, since data is bound when I am not using Spring Tag.

**Controller:**

I can debug `mav` object und look into `mav.model.materialStatistic.materialOccurences`. All `Float` values are properly set...

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loadMaterialStatistic(@ModelAttribute(value="materialStatistic") MaterialStatistic statistic,BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mav = showStatistic(statistic,"tab_material_statistic");
        if (!statistic.getSearchHelper().getMaterialNumber().isEmpty()) {
            MaterialStatistic statisticHelper = new MaterialStatistic(statistic.getSearchHelper());
            statisticHelper.setProjectMaterialDao(projectMaterialDao);
            mav.addObject("materialStatistic", statisticsService.fillStatistic(statisticHelper));
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

**Controller InitBinder**

```
binder.registerCustomEditor(Float.TYPE, "materialOccurences.averageM2", new StrictFloatPropertyEditor(true, false, request.getLocale()));
```

**StrictFloatPropertyEditor**:

.. but at `PropertyEditorSupport` Interceptor, `this.getValue()` is always `null`

```
@Override
    public String getAsText() {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(true);
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        String numberAsText = nf.format(this.getValue());
    }
```